# UITableView - Populating table with a bit complex data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Ok, I have a bit complex data that needs to be put in a custom table view. Below is the structure of `NSMutableDictionary`

```
cellData = [ "Section Header title" : NSMutableArray]; // NSMutableArray has custom cell objects
```

So, basically I'm tagging array of custom cell objects with its corresponding section header name. The problem is, I was unable to set the data to table view cell.
So far I've been dealing with...in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
HomeTableViewCell *cell = (HomeTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *sectionTitle = [sectionNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSMutableArray *array = [cellData objectForKey:sectionTitle];

if ([sectionTitle isEqual:@"Email"]) {
    Email *email = (Email*) [arr objectAtindex:indexPath.row]; // I know this is wrong because there're multiple objects in "array". I couldn't get it right
    [cell setCellData:...];
}
```

Just by using `indexPath.row` I couldn't get all the objects from "array". Anyone who tried populating custom table view cell with dictionary values like ("key" : "Array")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do is use indexPath.section when getting the section title:

```
NSString *sectionTitle = [sectionNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

Once you have the correct section your data should line up correctly.

Of course this assumes that you have your other methods set up correctly, namely:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
     return sectionNames.count;
}
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSString *sectionTitle = [sectionNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSMutableArray *array = [cellData objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    return array.count;

}
```

Comment: But how should I populate the data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, since I have array of custom objects paired to the section title? Using this `Email *email = (Email*) [arr objectAtindex:indexPath.row];` doesn't help right.

Comment: I got it! `indexPath.row` instead of `indexPath.section` ruined everything! Thank you.